# Передача данных JSON из контроллера Java в представление JS

Tags: javascript, java, json, mvc

Есть `jsp` страница, которая обрабатывает выпадающий список:

```
<div class="fetch-dc-block col-xs-4" align="right" id="ds">
  <%
    ......
  %>
  <select size="5" multiple="multiple" title="РЦ" id="dcsel"
    name="dcenters" align="right">
    <%
      .......
    <%
      }
    %>
  </select>
  <%
    ...
  %>
</div>
```

Мне нужно переписать эту логику на `js`. Для это я использую такую цепочку: контроллер берет данные, помещает их в `json` и через `response` передает их в представление.

Класс `java` с методом для контроллера:

```java
public class JsnResponse {
    public static <T> void sendJSONRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, T t) throws IOException {
        synchronized (response) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            String dataJson = gson.toJson(t);
            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            try {
                synchronized (pw) {
                    pw.print(dataJson);
                    pw.close();
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Syslog.error(JSONResponse.class, "Ошибка при записи PrintWriter");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void GetItem(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String[] rc = request.getParameterValues("dcsel");
        try {
            JSONResponse.sendJSONRequest(request, response, rc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь нужно как-то распарсить данные из `GetItem` в `js`. Как это грамотно сделать?

По идее я должен создать `js` файл, в котором пишу указание на мой метод:

```js
function GetItem() {
    $.getJSON(defaultPath + 'reports/GetItem', null, function (data) {
        arr = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите какой-то метод вызвать из `JavaScript`, то он там и должен быть, а у вас он на сервере в каком-то сервлете. Чтобы запустить этот метод, нужно вызывать сервлет, по его адресу.

Но лучше вызывать сервлет по адресу `/js/scriptname.js`, а в сервлете прописать, чтоб он не `JSON` возвращал, а прям сразу готовый скрипт и обновлял страницу со скриптом, а в скрипте прописать функцию `document.onload` и в ней страницу достраивать:

1. Написать сервлет с адресом `/js/scriptname.js`, в нем прописать метод, возвращающий `JS` файл с содержанием типа:

   ```java
   String result =
       "'use strict';\n" +
       "\n" +
       "$(window).on('load', fillForm);\n" +
       "\n" +
       "function fillForm() {\n" +
       "    let fieldName1 = document.getElementById('fieldName1');\n" +
       "    fieldName1.innerText = 'value1';\n" +
       "    // ...\n" +
       "    // Потом другие поля\n" +
       "}\n";
   ```
2. и вставить эту ссылку в `<head>` примерно так:

   ```html
   <script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/js/scriptname.js" defer></script>
   ```
3. после загрузки страницы, будет выполняться этот скрипт, который будет дозаполнять вашу страницу данными.

Comment: вот этот момент сложен мне для понимания "обновлял страницу со скриптом а в скрипте прописать функцию document.onload и в ней страницу достраивать."  можете пример кода дать? . я вызываю не метод, а результат json хочу распарсить в js.